# How to deserialize json with a blank field?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a json string like this:

```
[{
      "_id": "abcd",
      "name": "bender rodriguez",
      "meta": {
        "location": {}
      },
      dob": ,
}
]
```

The section after dob blows up:

```
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(json);
```

The problem is the empty dob. I cannot seem to find any method to handle something like this. Doesn't even seem to be a common problem? I'm not too familiar with deserializing json, what methods can I use to deal with this other than `string.replace(": ,"," : null,")`?

Comment: Where does the JSON come from? It's not currently valid with the empty value.

Comment: Are you sure you are missing the leading quote on the `dob": ,` line?  Or is that a typo in the question?

Comment: if the `dob"` property name is missing its leading quote, then every .Net JSON with which I am familiar will throw an exception.  But if this is a typo in the question and the property actually has its leading quote but is missing a value (i.e. `"dob": ,`), then [tag:json.net] is forgiving enough to parse the JSON.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/tZYQ00.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON deserialiser you're using is fine, the JSON you're trying to deserialice is wrong, it's missing a value, and the initial double quotes for the `dob` property.

Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate JSON.
If that JSON is coming from a component you control, then use a [JSON serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770(v=vs.100).aspx) to serialize it properly, if not, you can fix that particular problem using this:

```
string myJson = "[{ \"_id\": \"abcd\", \"name\": \"bender rodriguez\", \"meta\": { \"location\": {} }, dob\": , } ]";

JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(myJson.Replace("dob\": ", "\"dob\": \"\""));
```

But if the data changes and it keeps having an invalid JSON format, there's little you can do about it but asking whoever did that component to send you valid JSON data.